# KDE Plasma ' Archlinux: my cursor jumps and clicks everywhere and it has become more severe

Tags: linux, kde, plasma, cursor, autojump

**Problem:** my cursor jumps and clicks everywhere, and it has become more severe - it is maddening :'(

This question I have seen before in forums and tried their suggestions, but I still have this problem.

**What I tried:**

1. I found a possible solution: lowering KDE Plasma's sensitivity, but this dialogue window was gray colored.
2. Then I found the reason and solution for this graying: it was libinput. Here are the links I read:
   https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/d21mwv/why_are_my_touchpad_sensitivity_settings_greyed/
   and
   https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=130072 - see coryw Thu Mar 21.
   But removing libinput makes my keyboard non-functional.

**Now:** I do not know what I can do.

**System:** Arch-linux for Surface Pro 4 and KDE up to date.

Best and thank you in advance,

Roberto

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION!:** disable touch screen instead of touchpad, see:

[Mouse cursor jumping around the screen and clicking on HP Pavilion x360](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590012/mouse-cursor-jumping-around-the-screen-and-clicking-on-hp-pavilion-x360)

**This information tells you how to disable touch screens for Arch Linux:**

https://growworkinghard.altervista.org/enabledisable-touch-screen-on-arch-linux/

I hope others will solve this problem of a jumping cursor!

Comment: I found the solution: disable touchscreen instead of touchpad, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590012/mouse-cursor-jumping-around-the-screen-and-clicking-on-hp-pavilion-x360

Comment: Thank you for taking time to share a solution. When you want to provide a solution to your own question, please, don't edit your question post, but [post your solution in a separate answer post below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to maintain the Q&A format of this site.